# Why DNF is not obeying "max_parallel_downloads" from config file?

Tags: fedora, dnf

My DNF config file:

```
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
max_parallel_downloads=8
metadata_expire=-1
# exclude=kernel*
```

But DNF `4.2.8-2.fc30` in `Fedora 30` always uses `3` parallel downloads instead of `8`.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, this option `max_parallel_downloads` has not actually been implemented. I grepped through the installed Python source on my Fedora 30 laptop, and then searched the project's github repo, and found only the references in the documentation.

I would recommend filing a bug report.

Comment: The implementation is in `libdnf` and has been for at least three years.

Comment: @Aeyoun Yes, I finally found it in libdnf. So the question becomes why didn't it work?